# How does lightning:navigation replace lightning:openFiles?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I'm trying to develop functionality which allows a user to click on a link to display a preview of a single file or a set of files (`ContentDocuments`) in Lightning Experience. The obvious way to do this is to use the [`lightning:openFiles`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:openFiles/documentation) event, apart from the fact that this is "no longer recommended".

Within the documentation for `lightning:openFiles`, Salesforce recommend "Use the Lightning navigation service instead". I cannot find how to use the [Lightning navigation service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) to implement this functionality in the same way.

I've reviewed the documentation in the [Component Reference for lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation), and also the linked documentation for [Page Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm) and [PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm), and couldn't find any reference for how to open a ContentDocument in the previewer.

I tried the following page reference:

```
{
    type: "standard__recordPage",
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: "ContentDocument",
        recordId: "069000000000000000",
        actionName: "view"
    }
}
```

This successfully redirects to the file, but doesn't open it in preview mode. I tried changing the `actionName` to `preview` or `open`, neither of which was successful.

I'm imagining that I might want to vary the `type`, but I'm also just wondering if the documentation is sending me barking up the wrong tree. If I use the `lightning:fileCard` component, which implements the behaviour I want, I can see that this still fires `lightning:openFiles` events, so the event is still used by Salesforce internally even if discouraged.

Does anyone know the "proper" way to replicate `lightning:openFiles` behaviour using `lightning:navigation`?

Comment: I also use the `lightning:openFiles` component - for a file previewer. It is excellent and the only drawback is that if the user has file access - it gives full manage capabilities for the user on the file. I think that they recommend "Use the Lightning navigation service instead" , means that you should implement your own previewer - they do not supply more than navigation on the navigation service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page reference is wrong. It's documented in the [LWC Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_open_files), and should look like this:

```
{
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview',
            },
            state : {
                recordIds: '069xxxxxxxxxxx,0691yyyyyyyyyyyyy',
                selectedRecordId:'069xxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @angelsalazar. Could you provide a reference to the documentation for this? I see "filePreview" is now listed under the "Named Page" entry since Spring 19, but can't see where the state parameters are documented. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm#named_page

Comment: I found it in the lwc documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_open_files

Comment: @James Right now, it is not supported in Lightning Components for Visualforce, Lightning Out, or Experience Cloud sites